# "specify" in Java exception handling

Tags: java, exception

This is rather a verification.

On Oracle/Java tutorial pages such as [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), I keep seeing
"**specify**" right next to **catch** as if it is another statement
with some functionality in exception handling.

From what I know, "specify" in "catch or specify" is referring to
the mandatory specification of a checked exception with **throws**
in the method declaration unless it is caught and handled. (Unchecked methods
can very well be specified as well but not mandatory in that case.)

However, this isn't pinned down in any of these pages and "specify" is formatted as if it is a keyword although it [isn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where do you see 'specify'? Ctrl+F can't find it.

Comment: I think your first link is pointing to the wrong page.

Comment: corrected. thx for the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing nothing as far as I know. The `specify` means the method declaration. Perhaps they used code markup to clearly distinguish that both are equivalent code approaches? Might be a simple mistake as well.

> Why did the designers decide to force a method to specify all uncaught
> checked exceptions that can be thrown within its scope? Any Exception
> that can be thrown by a method is part of the method's public
> programming interface.

[Unchecked exceptions - The controversy (javadocs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Comment: helps me verify altough i dont see what the quote and the part after is adding on. thx for tha ans.

Comment: The quote shows that they use `specify` as a way to describe the exception added to the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

They're just referring to the [catch or specify requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html). It looks like they made a formatting error when they put "specify" in the monospaced font.

Comment: it`s not the only p.they made it.

Comment: Hm, then I guess they must have made a conscious decision to format it that way. I agree with you that it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> If a method chooses not to catch an exception, the method must specify
>   that it can throw that exception. Why did the Java designers make this
>   requirement? Because any exception that can be thrown by a method is
>   really part of the method's public programming interface: callers of a
>   method must know about the exceptions that a method can throw in order
>   to intelligently and consciously decide what to do about those
>   exceptions. Thus, in the method signature you specify the exceptions
>   that the method can throw.

as seen here:http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

And "specify" is not a keyword (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), they're just talking about specifying the exceptions a method will throw in the method declaration

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.